# Populating DetailController from UITableViewCell via segue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsmanagedobject

I am populating cells in a `UITableView` from `CoreData` and I have a question about how best to transfer the data I need to my `DetailController` (i.e. the `viewController` that shows when the cell is tapped).

Currently when populating the `UITableViewCell`s I use the `indexPath` passed to the cell to retrieve the appropriate `managedObject` from Core Data. At this stage I only update the cell with a few bits of information from the managed object (i.e. name, age, sex).

After the `UITableView` has been fully populated I want to allow users to select a `UITableViewCell` and present a `DetailController` showing more in-depth information (i.e. name, age, sex, occupation, weight, height etc.) When the cell is tapped I am using `-prepareForSegue` to transition to the newly presented `DetailController`.

#### My question:

The "sender" for the segue is the `UITableViewCell` (subclass) but I have only populated this with the information I needed to originally display in the smaller cell. Should I

1. add more iVars to the `UITableViewCell` subclass and store all the data
   I need,
2. keep a pointer iVar on the cell to the model `managedObject`
3. something else that I might have missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern we use in objective-c Your views should never know about your data model. This means that your `UITableViewCell`s should not have any properties that store objects from your data model. Cells should only have labels and views as properties which your view controller fills in with data from the model in its `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method or similar

You get the `UITableViewCell` object as the sender in prepare for segue. You can find out the index path for the cell with the following method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSIndexPath * selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    ...
```

You can then use this index path to pull your model object out of core data again, and set it as a property on your next view controller, or whatever you need to do to pass the model object forward